# Web Service certs and windows cert store

Tags: c#, web-services, x509certificate2

[Widows 10 / Windows Server 2016]

At a site we have a web service (ours) calls another web service (theirs) in which they require a certificate with the request.
The web service is running an app pool under the standard “Network Service” user.
This certificate is imported into the Personal Store on the Local Machine.
This certificate does NOT have a private key so that removes the right click -> All Tasks -> Manage Private keys fix.  Yes I realize it’s a very odd arrangement, but it is beyond our control.

Running in the web service, when we do a find cert by thumbprint option from the store, it finds 0 thumbprints.  No faults or exceptions, just 0 results.  However, you can iterate that store that you requested it from and dump the thumbprints to a log and clearly see it is present.

We also use the same code in a desktop client, in the same manner and it finds the cert just fine. Our client desktop application calls their web service with the same cert.

For the web service version we have a config item that, when set, loads the Cert from the file that was used to load it into the key store and the web service has no problem with the cert when loaded that way.

When you look at the cert in the cert manager it shows that it is perfectly valid with no issues.

We have tried replicating the conditions in the lab and the setup works just fine here (of course).

Anyone have any thoughts on other things to check?

---

Addendum:

//Discovery code:
//

```
string thumbprint = LoadThumbprintFromConfig();

LogManager.LogTrace($"Searching for thumbprint [{thumbprint}]");

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

//The immensely complex search query:
X509CertificateCollection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true);
X509Certificate2 rval = (col.Count > 0) ? (X509Certificate2)col[0] : null;
```

---

//cert examination code:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

List<string> logEntry = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i < store.Certificates.Count; i++)
{
   logEntry.Add($"{store.Certificates[i].Thumbprint}");
}

LogManager.LogTrace(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, logEntry));
```

Comment: The certificate has to be loaded in both the machine and user stores.  You should be able to verified this in the registry.  The version of TLS should be the same on all machines to using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler compare the version of TLS on working and non working machines.  What version of core and Net are you using?

Comment: This generation uses Framework 4.6.2.  I'm not even talking about trying to USE the cert at the point of failure, just trying to read it from the store. So there is literally not yet been any network traffic to sniff because the request to the other web service has not yet been made.

Comment: What encryption method is being used in the cerfiicate?  Check the text in the certificate.  There are fixes in framework 4.7.2 that may be required.

Comment: Does the service account under which the web service is running have permissions on the certificate?

Comment: @jdweng I'd have to check with the site admin. Encryption method isn't something that's come up in conversation. There is a coast to coast time zone difference and a significant bureaucracy to penetrate when working with them (it took a month to get a testing patch to their site system).

Comment: @Charlieface For permissions, you can’t set permissions on a cert that doesn’t contain a private key. It can get to the store and see all the certs in the store because I’ve iterated the certs and dumped all the thumbprints to a log

Comment: TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not obsolete and you must use TLS 1.2 or 1.3.  Not all versions of Net/Core work with 1.2 and 1.3.  Also Microsoft has moved the implimentation of TLS from Net/Core to using the machine dlls to do the TLS.  So it is complicated to determine if TLS 1.2 and 1.3 will work on a machine.  To check which encrytion modes will work with each version of TLS see Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: @jdweng   True, I've even seen strange things where our lab refuses to work when I explicitly set TLS1.3 but our dev system is fine with it but wants TLS1.2 specified as an option and the lab doesn't care. Which is really weird since the lab systems are typically locked down tighter than dev systems.  Either way, not the problem I'm trying to solve in this context.  There might be a problem down the line regarding this but it is rendered moot since it can't seem to pull the cert from the store at site (works fine in dev/lab).

Comment: Is certificate load for both user and machine?  I've read someplace that the certificate is needed in both.   As part of the TLS authentication the server send a certificate block with the certificate names the server can use.  Then client looks up the certificates to see if there is a match by name.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and look at the certificate names in the TLS certificate block which is not encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

> This certificate does NOT have a private key so that removes the right click -> All Tasks -> Manage Private keys fix. Yes I realize it’s a very odd arrangement, but it is beyond our control.

this certificate cannot be used for client authentication. Only certificates with private keys can be used for client authentication.

> Running in the web service, when we do a find cert by thumbprint option from the store, it finds 0 thumbprints.

this means that your search query is incorrect. Where is your code?

> For the web service version we have a config item that, when set, loads the Cert from the file that was used to load it into the key store and the web service has no problem with the cert when loaded that way.

where is your code?

---

**Update 1:**

based on your provided code this call:

```
X509CertificateCollection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true);
```

has last paramter set to `true`, which requires only valid certificates. It seems, the certificate you are fetching isn't valid/trusted. Iteration shows all the certs regardless of their statuses, but `Find` method has some extra logic. If target certificate's `.HasPrivateKey` property is `false`, then you are out of business, you can't do anything until you get a certificate with private key.

Comment: I am aware that certs that don’t have a private key are not valid for client authentication.  This is because they use the private key to sign the message and the public key is used to validate that signature.  We have pointed this out to the other service provider, but they are the ones that dictate what to use for their service, I’m guessing they’re not that concerned because it’s on a private (non internet) network. Not the problem I’m trying to solve at this point either way.
Added the ‘immensely complex’ search query to description.

Comment: sorry, we can't solve provider's incompetency. See my updated response on cert search code.

Comment: I discovered the 3rd true parameter for valid in the early tests as well.  I simulated it in our environment by taking the cert that we had and exporting it without the private key.  I deleted it in the store and re-imported the one without the private key.  It still discovered the cert just fine since the cert itself is still valid.